# COMO SUMAR UN 1 A UN VECTOR EN PYTHON SIN USAR NUMPY

Tags: python, array

Hola soy principiante en python y estaba haciendo un vector, queria sumarle 1 a cada uno de sus elementos sin usar numpy sino con un for, entonces intente hacer esto:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np
vector3= []
def arreglo_suma (vector,T):
    for i in range(0,T):
        vector3[i]=vector[i+1]
    return vector3[i]



if __name__ == "__main__":
    resultado=[]
    vector =[4,5,6,7,8,2,1]
    T= len(vector)
    resultado= arreglo_suma (vector,T)
    print(resultado)
```

pero a la hora de compilarlo me sale este error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "suma.py", line 15, in <module>
    resultado= arreglo_suma (vector,T)
  File "suma.py", line 6, in arreglo_suma
    vector3[i]=vector[i+1]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: `vector3[i]=vector[i+1]` hay 3 problemas en esta sentencia 1) vector3 no existe en el scope de la función 2) Eventualmente si corriges lo anterior, no puedes asignar un valor a una lista vacía, en todo caso deberías usar vector3.append() 3) `vector[i+1]` cuando llegues al último índice te va a dar error por que estás accediendo a un elemento+1 que no existe

Comment: @PatricioMoracho te agrego el cuarto.. quiere sumar 1 a cada posicion del vector.. o sea.. que quiere vector3[i]++.. o vector3[i]+1 ;)

Comment: ¿Para qué el import numpy si un requisito era no usarlo? ¿y para qué el import ctypes?

Comment: @abulafia hola, era porque voy a intentar comparar el tiempo de ejecución de la misma tarea por varios métodos, conectando con C, con asm, con la libreria numpy y con el for para calcular la efectividad y hacer graficos del tiempo de ejecucion :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se puede hacer con una comprensión de lista:

```
resultado = [x + 1 for x in vector]
```

Esta instrucción crea una nueva lista (`resultado`) donde cada elemento es igual al correspondiente en `vector` + 1.

Esta comprensión es equivalente a la versión más larga:

```
resultado = []
for i in vector:
    resultado.append(i + 1)
```

#### Demo

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    resultado=[]
    vector =[4,5,6,7,8,2,1]
    resultado = [x + 1 for x in vector]
    print(resultado)
```

produce:

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3, 2]

Process finished with exit code 0
```